# Synchronizing javascript functions with promises, socket.io emit

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, socket.io, synchronous

I'm building a web app and am trying to emit data to a server in a particular order, using socket.io's emit().  Basically, I'm trying to send two sets of data synchronously and then a "submit" message after both previous sets of data (`steps` and `files`) are completely sent.  My problem is that the "submit" message is sent before the files has finished being sent.  I'm trying to use `Promises` but it's not working, and I'm guessing there's a mistake with the usage.

```
sendToServer() {
    Promise.all([
        new Promise((res) => res(this.sendSteps())),
        new Promise((res) => res(this.sendFiles()))
    ]).then(this.sendSubmit());
}
```

**Update:**

I also tried this but it doesn't solve the problem.  sendSubmit() still starts before sendFiles() is done.

```
async sendToServer() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => res(this.sendSteps()))
        .then(() => {
            return new Promise((res, rej) => res(this.sendFiles()));
        })
        .then(() => {
            return new Promise((res, rej) => res(this.sendSubmit()));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please rewrite the code like this and let me know.

```
sendToServer() {
    Promise.all([
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(this.sendSteps())),
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(this.sendFiles()))
    ]).then(()=>{
        this.sendSubmit();
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the problem is still there.  Just to be clear, this.sendSteps() and this.sendFiles() don't need to be promises themselves, right?  They can just be normal functions?

Comment: According to your code snippet it's not important.